# swift status bar over web page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

So here's the problem, I am using WebKit, i set up a button which when clicked loads a website using NSURL. The problem is I need this website to load within the app(have that part covered) but when it does load the web page does not take the status bar in consideration. I posted a picture here with loading in just google.com (http://postimg.org/image/dncilg139/). The battery is touching the sign in portion of the website. I need a way for the web page to shift below the notification center. I need this in the new language SWIFT.

Comment: That is the status bar not the notification bar. Please provide details of how you are adding this view to the native app. e.g. autoLayout or using frames

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make this look correct is to add a  UINavigationController to this scene in your storyboard. Select your UIViewController or UIWebViewController from the storyboard and from the menu select Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller.